# Can I hide Android/Oracle classes in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Since I've installed Android plugin into my Eclipse, all JDK classes are shown twice, e.g., there's `StringBuilder` from `java-7-oracle` and from `android-7`. This is quite annoying and I'd love a possibility to hide one of them (either manually or based on the current project).

Using two workspaces or two completely different Eclipse installations would be fine, too, providing it works fine. What is the best practice?

---

I see that my question was misunderstood: When I invoke "Open Type" (ctrl-alt-t) I get listed all JDK classes multiple times. Any chance to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy, you can set your JDK version projectwise in eclise. Please look at following steps

1. Right Click on Project and Select Properties
2. From the dialog box's left side, select **Java Compiler**
3. Check the "Enable Project Specific Settings"
4. From the right side's Version Combo-Box, select your version to compile, done

This way you can set Project with JDK Version for different different project.

Comment: I can't see it [there](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/published/120527/javaCompilerSettings.png), there are only compliance settings (Java 1.3 to 1.7).

Comment: yes, that 1.7 is your JDK version, you can select as per your project requirement.